# How to get BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON to work?

Tags: c++, api, winapi

My button has these styles:

```
WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON
```

it creates and lights up properly, but in my edit control, when i press ENTER, it does nothing!

Heres the styles of my edit control:

```
WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
```

I am not using a dialog, i have created my windows using CreateWindow() and i have handled tab order in the message loop:

```
MSG msg;
while (GetMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    if (!IsDialogMessage(hActiveWindow, &msg))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

The "hActiveWindow" is a handle to the window that the user has currently active. tabbing works but i have a feeling this is messing wiht the DEFPUSHBUTTON.

any help?

Comment: A side note, your while should be entered as `while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)`. GetMessage can return -1 on error

Comment: Just for fun take out the if (!IsDialogMessage(hActiveWindow, &msg))
line. What happens?

Comment: stays the same apart from i have no tabbing

Comment: also would like to note that if i put my own window procedure onto my edit box, with SetWIndowLong, i can handle any key in the WM_KEYDOWN, but if i try to handle VK_RETURN, it doesn't work

Comment: Edit controls does not handle the Enter key as a key in that manner. If you need to you should set the `ES_WANTRETURN` style. Although, I just read on msdn that if this is not set the default mode is to call the default button, so why you are getting the first issue, I cannot say..: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775464(VS.85).aspx

Comment: There are just too many unknowns. If you want an answer, I think you'll have to provide more information.

Comment: but i have tried this many times on other applications, and i can't get it to work. the only time defpushbutton works for me is on a dialog created in resources. I noticed i can handle a WM_KEYUP for the VK_RETURN on my edit window procedure, but can't handle it on KEYDOWN.

Comment: Just noticed that when i press enter on the edit control, i recieve a BN_CLICKED  notification in the HIWORD of the WPARAM, but in the LOWORD it contains 1, when my button has an id code of 2003

Comment: For your information: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/102589. Notice "If the dialog box does not have a default command button, then the idItem parameter is set to IDOK by default", and IDOK is defined as 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be that your button is not set to be default. One solution could be to set the default button behavior with the [DM_SETDEFID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645413(VS.85).aspx)

```
/*
in: win: HWND of the window you have
in: id: your id of your default button
*/
SendMessage(win, DM_SETDEFID, id, 0);
```

Comment: It seems that when you press enter it sends the loword of wparam as ID 1, so i have been using that :) though i support this sets it to any number you want? thanks for the reply.

Comment: yup, the comment I added to your post explained that: the default value is IDOK, which is defined as 1. I'm glad you worked it out though :)

Comment: My understanding is that DM_SETDEFID only works if you are using DefDlgProc i.e. via CreateDialog, which means it won't work with CreateWindow which is what the question specifies.